# Subscribe to Exchange Server Calendar from within my Web Site

Tags: calendar, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to build a calendar for my site, which users can use to connect and fetch/subscribe to all the various accounts a user has. I do not wish to get any other information regarding his contacts, etc.

Is there any API available which allows me to import or subscribe to an Exchange server to get just the Calendar of the user?

As yet I have have able to find these 2 resources, but they do not provide a good description of how and what is to be done for web site and DB integration:

For Google Calendar API:

```
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/
```

For Outlook Exchange API:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj190901%28exchg.150%29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook Exchange API you pointed to above (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj190901%28exchg.150%29) is what we call Mail apps - and they are always hosted in Outlook, so that's not the right technology for publishing to a website. You can get access to a user's calendar programmatically by using Exchange Web Services (EWS), which is SOAP based, or the EWS Managed API, which is a managed wrapper for EWS. More information about EWS vs EWS Managed API is provided here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579177(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579177%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). Specific information about accessing an Exchange Calendar using EWS or the EWS Managed API is provided in this topic and its subtopics: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495623(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495623%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). This info does not provide information about website integration though - it's specific to the calendaring API functionality.

Comment: I wanted to add one more piece of info, if you're using O365, the Office 365 APIs, specifically the Mail Rest APIs are another option and are discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896(v=office.15).aspx.